# Generate high frequency clock output in Stratix II

Tags: fpga, timing, intel-fpga

Using a Stratix II FPGA is it possible to generate a clock output with a frequency much higher than 200MHz? (Up to 400 or 500MHz) If so how can I achieve this?
I used a PLL to generate 200MHz out of a 100MHz clock and this seems to work. But turning the PLL to 250MHz will make the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer reporting a negative setup slack for the PLL in the slow model. So I wonder if there is a better way to generate such high frequency clock outputs...

Comment: How do you get this high frequency signal over the board? What connector are you using? I don't if it works (is the I/O standard compatible) but the transceivers can handle up to 6 GHz. You could send a 0101 pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I couldn't find documentation about transceivers in the Stratix II documentation (only for Stratix II GX), so I'm not sure they are supported. Although there is a ALTLVDS_TX megafunction available in Quartus...

I found the reason of the frequency limitation being a forgotten counter driven by the PLL output for testing purposes. Not the PLL as I initially thought :-O

So the frequency is fine, although I'm stuck now at the stage you mentioned to get the signal to an output pin, which isn't as straight forward as assumed.

Comment: I always get a Quartus Warning:
PLL ... output port clk[1] feeds output pin 'clk' via non-dedicated routing ... Use PLL dedicated clock outputs to ensure jitter performance ...

Comment: http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-1104.html
shows I can either use a hardwired PLL output pin, although I couldn't figure out yet which pin this would be and how I would eventually put a cable to this pin. Or I could use a regional clock network to pass the PLL output to an arbitrary I/O pin. 
I tried the regional clock network version ("PLL -> ALTCLKCTRL -> I/O pin" should do the trick, right?)
But still I get the jitter warning.
I also checked the PLL and altclkctrl user guides, but still couldn't solve this (easy?) problem.

Comment: Yes, pure Stratix II FPGAs have no transceivers. Tunneling a clock signal through the FPGA adds jitter to the signal, because the clock drivers in the clock tree are influenced by the switching parts in FPGA, but it's better to use a clock tree for tunneling instead of general purpose routing resources. I think you can ignore the warning. You could also use a DDR-I/O flipflop to drive the I/O pin for a better duty cycle. The flipflop is called `altddio_out`. Here is an usage example in [PoC.io.ddrio.out_altera](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/io/ddrio/ddrio_out_altera.vhdl).

Comment: ... set `BITS = 1`, connect `DataOut_high` to "1" and `DataOut_low` to "0".